# Can't position div 50% height css

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. I need strictly position my div vertically right. But i can't set % and if i set px it looks very bad on different screen sizes.

So

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100% !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: 15px;
}

.child_button {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <div class="child_button">Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So child button not going to the 50% on the height and it moves only if i set top in px not in %

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The `html`, `body` and `.parent` elements all need a base height of `100%` for it to do what you expect. `max-height` doesn't set a height, just enforces a maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set body height and your parent should have height property as well. Also, `div` element between parent and child should be height 100%

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
.parent {
    display: block;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    bottom: auto; 
    left: auto; 
    right: 15px;

  }
  
  .parent > div {
    height: 100%;
  }

.child_button {
position: relative; 
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
      <div class="child_button">Text
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.child_button {
  padding: 10px; 
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 19px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <div class="child_button">Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could tweak the calc value depending on the height of your button.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're translating/giving margin to your child div in terms of it's own height, that's why it's not working.

The most modern solution would probably be to use flexbox and

```
align-items: center;
```

but Observer's solution works just fine and fits your code.